# use three.js on the wordpress page

Tags: javascript, wordpress, three.js

I want to use `three.js` [bird sample](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_gpgpu_birds) in my WordPress website in top of a page. In my header I placed

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://somesite.com/wp-content/themes/theme/assets/js/three.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://somesite.com/wp-content/themes/theme/assets/js/Projector.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://somesite.com/wp-content/themes/theme/assets/js/CanvasRenderer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://somesite.com/wp-content/themes/theme/assets/js/stats.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://somesite.com/wp-content/themes/theme/assets/js/Bird.js"></script>
```

and when I use visual composer js block to display

```
    <script>

            // Based on http://www.openprocessing.org/visuals/?visualID=6910

            var Boid = function() {

                var vector = new THREE.Vector3(),
                _acceleration, _width = 500, _height = 500, _depth = 200, _goal, _neighborhoodRadius = 100,
                _maxSpeed = 4, _maxSteerForce = 0.1, _avoidWalls = false;

                this.position = new THREE.Vector3();
                this.velocity = new THREE.Vector3();
                _acceleration = new THREE.Vector3();

                this.setGoal = function ( target ) {

                    _goal = target;

                };

                this.setAvoidWalls = function ( value ) {

                    _avoidWalls = value;

                };

                this.setWorldSize = function ( width, height, depth ) {

                    _width = width;
                    _height = height;
                    _depth = depth;

                };

                this.run = function ( boids ) {

                    if ( _avoidWalls ) {

                        vector.set( - _width, this.position.y, this.position.z );
                        vector = this.avoid( vector );
                        vector.multiplyScalar( 5 );
                        _acceleration.add( vector );

                        vector.set( _width, this.position.y, this.position.z );
                        vector = this.avoid( vector );
                        vector.multiplyScalar( 5 );
                        _acceleration.add( vector );

                        vector.set( this.position.x, - _height, this.position.z );
                        vector = this.avoid( vector );
                        vector.multiplyScalar( 5 );
                        _acceleration.add( vector );

                        vector.set( this.position.x, _height, this.position.z );
                        vector = this.avoid( vector );
                        vector.multiplyScalar( 5 );
                        _acceleration.add( vector );

                        vector.set( this.position.x, this.position.y, - _depth );
                        vector = this.avoid( vector );
                        vector.multiplyScalar( 5 );
                        _acceleration.add( vector );

                        vector.set( this.position.x, this.position.y, _depth );
                        vector = this.avoid( vector );
                        vector.multiplyScalar( 5 );
                        _acceleration.add( vector );

                    }/* else {

                        this.checkBounds();

                    }
                    */

                    if ( Math.random() > 0.5 ) {

                        this.flock( boids );

                    }

                    this.move();

                };

                this.flock = function ( boids ) {

                    if ( _goal ) {

                        _acceleration.add( this.reach( _goal, 0.005 ) );

                    }

                    _acceleration.add( this.alignment( boids ) );
                    _acceleration.add( this.cohesion( boids ) );
                    _acceleration.add( this.separation( boids ) );

                };

                this.move = function () {

                    this.velocity.add( _acceleration );

                    var l = this.velocity.length();

                    if ( l > _maxSpeed ) {

                        this.velocity.divideScalar( l / _maxSpeed );

                    }

                    this.position.add( this.velocity );
                    _acceleration.set( 0, 0, 0 );

                };

                this.checkBounds = function () {

                    if ( this.position.x >   _width ) this.position.x = - _width;
                    if ( this.position.x < - _width ) this.position.x =   _width;
                    if ( this.position.y >   _height ) this.position.y = - _height;
                    if ( this.position.y < - _height ) this.position.y =  _height;
                    if ( this.position.z >  _depth ) this.position.z = - _depth;
                    if ( this.position.z < - _depth ) this.position.z =  _depth;

                };

                //

                this.avoid = function ( target ) {

                    var steer = new THREE.Vector3();

                    steer.copy( this.position );
                    steer.sub( target );

                    steer.multiplyScalar( 1 / this.position.distanceToSquared( target ) );

                    return steer;

                };

                this.repulse = function ( target ) {

                    var distance = this.position.distanceTo( target );

                    if ( distance < 150 ) {

                        var steer = new THREE.Vector3();

                        steer.subVectors( this.position, target );
                        steer.multiplyScalar( 0.5 / distance );

                        _acceleration.add( steer );

                    }

                };

                this.reach = function ( target, amount ) {

                    var steer = new THREE.Vector3();

                    steer.subVectors( target, this.position );
                    steer.multiplyScalar( amount );

                    return steer;

                };

                this.alignment = function ( boids ) {

                    var boid, velSum = new THREE.Vector3(),
                    count = 0;

                    for ( var i = 0, il = boids.length; i < il; i++ ) {

                        if ( Math.random() > 0.6 ) continue;

                        boid = boids[ i ];

                        distance = boid.position.distanceTo( this.position );

                        if ( distance > 0 && distance <= _neighborhoodRadius ) {

                            velSum.add( boid.velocity );
                            count++;

                        }

                    }

                    if ( count > 0 ) {

                        velSum.divideScalar( count );

                        var l = velSum.length();

                        if ( l > _maxSteerForce ) {

                            velSum.divideScalar( l / _maxSteerForce );

                        }

                    }

                    return velSum;

                };

                this.cohesion = function ( boids ) {

                    var boid, distance,
                    posSum = new THREE.Vector3(),
                    steer = new THREE.Vector3(),
                    count = 0;

                    for ( var i = 0, il = boids.length; i < il; i ++ ) {

                        if ( Math.random() > 0.6 ) continue;

                        boid = boids[ i ];
                        distance = boid.position.distanceTo( this.position );

                        if ( distance > 0 && distance <= _neighborhoodRadius ) {

                            posSum.add( boid.position );
                            count++;

                        }

                    }

                    if ( count > 0 ) {

                        posSum.divideScalar( count );

                    }

                    steer.subVectors( posSum, this.position );

                    var l = steer.length();

                    if ( l > _maxSteerForce ) {

                        steer.divideScalar( l / _maxSteerForce );

                    }

                    return steer;

                };

                this.separation = function ( boids ) {

                    var boid, distance,
                    posSum = new THREE.Vector3(),
                    repulse = new THREE.Vector3();

                    for ( var i = 0, il = boids.length; i < il; i ++ ) {

                        if ( Math.random() > 0.6 ) continue;

                        boid = boids[ i ];
                        distance = boid.position.distanceTo( this.position );

                        if ( distance > 0 && distance <= _neighborhoodRadius ) {

                            repulse.subVectors( this.position, boid.position );
                            repulse.normalize();
                            repulse.divideScalar( distance );
                            posSum.add( repulse );

                        }

                    }

                    return posSum;

                }

            }

        </script>

        <script>

            var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth,
            SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight,
            SCREEN_WIDTH_HALF = SCREEN_WIDTH  / 2,
            SCREEN_HEIGHT_HALF = SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2;

            var camera, scene, renderer,
            birds, bird;

            var boid, boids;

            var stats;

            init();
            animate();

            function init() {

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT, 1, 10000 );
                camera.position.z = 450;

                scene = new THREE.Scene();

                birds = [];
                boids = [];

                for ( var i = 0; i < 200; i ++ ) {

                    boid = boids[ i ] = new Boid();
                    boid.position.x = Math.random() * 400 - 200;
                    boid.position.y = Math.random() * 400 - 200;
                    boid.position.z = Math.random() * 400 - 200;
                    boid.velocity.x = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
                    boid.velocity.y = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
                    boid.velocity.z = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
                    boid.setAvoidWalls( true );
                    boid.setWorldSize( 500, 500, 400 );

                    bird = birds[ i ] = new THREE.Mesh( new Bird(), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color:Math.random() * 0xffffff, side: THREE.DoubleSide } ) );
                    bird.phase = Math.floor( Math.random() * 62.83 );
                    scene.add( bird );


                }

                renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
                renderer.setClearColor( 0xffffff );
                renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
                renderer.setSize( SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT );

                document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
                document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                stats = new Stats();
                document.getElementById( 'container' ).appendChild(stats.dom);

                //

                window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

            }

            function onWindowResize() {

                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

            }

            function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {

                var vector = new THREE.Vector3( event.clientX - SCREEN_WIDTH_HALF, - event.clientY + SCREEN_HEIGHT_HALF, 0 );

                for ( var i = 0, il = boids.length; i < il; i++ ) {

                    boid = boids[ i ];

                    vector.z = boid.position.z;

                    boid.repulse( vector );

                }

            }

            //

            function animate() {

                requestAnimationFrame( animate );

                stats.begin();
                render();
                stats.end();

            }

            function render() {

                for ( var i = 0, il = birds.length; i < il; i++ ) {

                    boid = boids[ i ];
                    boid.run( boids );

                    bird = birds[ i ];
                    bird.position.copy( boids[ i ].position );

                    color = bird.material.color;
                    color.r = color.g = color.b = ( 500 - bird.position.z ) / 1000;

                    bird.rotation.y = Math.atan2( - boid.velocity.z, boid.velocity.x );
                    bird.rotation.z = Math.asin( boid.velocity.y / boid.velocity.length() );

                    bird.phase = ( bird.phase + ( Math.max( 0, bird.rotation.z ) + 0.1 )  ) % 62.83;
                    bird.geometry.vertices[ 5 ].y = bird.geometry.vertices[ 4 ].y = Math.sin( bird.phase ) * 5;

                }

                renderer.render( scene, camera );

            }

        </script>
```

nothing is showing up. I tested in html on local machine, and it was working fine. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Any errors in your console?

Comment: solved its server problem i doing it right ! tQ Dingo .